# JS: Setting checked to true is not working

Tags: javascript, dom, checkbox

Trying to set a Checkbox via addEventListener in JS, I already tried with

> ```
> element.checked = true;
> element.setAttribute('checked', true);
> element.setAttribute('checked', "checked");
> ```

I can see in the console that my checked is set to true (not sure if the issue is that the boolean value is shown as string "true" or if this is just a chrome representation) but the element is not getting the check mark.

> input id="element" class="element" name="element" type="checkbox"
>   value="1" checked="true"

Onload the default checked box is correctly set but when I'm trying to uncheck and set the new one nothing is happening (visually).

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please provide a **runnable** [mcve] that reproduces the issue. There isn't enough code context provided

Comment: Setting `checked = true` should work. There's something else going on, but what that is is impossible to tell without code to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do but I think you want to toggle one checkbox depending on the state of another.

Have a look at this:

```js
/* get the checkboxes */
const checker1 = document.getElementById('checker');
const checker2 = document.getElementById('checker2');

/* now listen for change on checker1 and action */
/* change the selected state of checker two to be opposite of checker 1 */
checker1.addEventListener('change', () => checker2.checked = !checker1.checked);
```

```html
<p>
  <label for=checker>Click me to toggle the other</label>
  <input type=checkbox id=checker>
</p>

<p>
  <label>I will be toggled</label>
  <input type=checkbox id=checker2 checked>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

So the thing is that if you were supposed to do this manually, Your code would have been like this right:

```html
<input id="element" checked>
```

In order to achieve the same thing using javascript. It would only happen if you set the checked value to an empty string. Like this:

```js
element.setAttribute("checked","");
```

This will let your output be like that above.
HOPE IT WORKED OUT FOR YOU :)